# Copy Qt4's DLLs with CMake

Tags: dll, qt4, copy, cmake

I want to copy QtCore4.dll and QtGui4.dll in my Install/ dir as a post-build step.

In CMake, the QT4 package defines variables like ${QT_DOC_DIR}, but not ${QT_BIN_DIR}. So what I ended up doing is :

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET blahblah
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${QT_DOC_DIR}/../bin/QtCore4.dll ${INSTDIR}
)
```

Ugly, and problably only works on Windows.

Is there a variable I'm not aware of ? Or should I do completely another way ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why would you want to do this outside Windows? In Linux you should use the distribution provided Qt packages. OTOH, I must admit I have no idea if this is necessary on MacOS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From share/cmake-2.8/modules/FindQt4.cmake :

```
#  QT_BINARY_DIR               Path to "bin" of Qt4
```

I wasn't too far away with QT_BIN_DIR...